# Как и где может теряться сессия или кука JSESSIONID на сервере jboss?

Tags: jboss, servlet, сессия, java, сервер

На продакшн сервере возникает ошибка, не воспроизводимая на других. После процесса аутентификации на определенной странице, по-видимому, где-то в цепочке фильтров. Выяснил, что на этом сервере до захода на эту определенную страницу теряется JSESSIONID, но в дальнейшем "подменяется" другим значение (в коде нашел использование getSession(true), что означает "если нет сессии - создай ее").

Вопрос в том, какая есть **ПРИНЦИПИАЛЬНАЯ** возможность утраты сессии? Может, подсказкой послужит, что на этом сервере используется "кластеризация"? Что нужно искать в коде (сам искал removeAttribute() и установку хедера, но ничего такого не нашел) или какие возможности утраты сессии существуют при работе сервера jboss?

Comment: Похоже, сессия теряется при редиректе с https to http. Возможно в этом и есть причина...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Кластеризация сервера](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/cluster.concepts.chapt.html#clustering-concepts-def) означает, что сервер(а) работают на нескольких физических (или виртуальных) серверах, которые с точки зрения внешнего юзера/запроса работают как 1 сервер. Существует множество разных механизмов кластеризации - либо несколько инстансов веб сервера на разных нодах объединены в один сервер, либо кластеризация работает на уровне БД и т.д. Общим местом является т.н. синхронизация между серверами (нодами) кластера. Этим обычно управляет специальное приложение *session replication service*. В настройках приложения иногда требуется указывать специальные атрибуты, чтобы сообщить сервису репликаций, что данное приложение может быть распределенным, в некоторых серверах это происходит по умолчанию.

Я не великий специалист по JBoss, но короткое гугление приводит к [такой ссылке](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/clustering-http-app.html) - поройтесь в документации. Скорее всего сессия у вас теряется из-за неверных настроек репликации сессий между нодами кластера.